# Weka ,Text Classification on an arff file

Tags: weka, text-classification

.This is a basic question .I am trying to classify text files into 20 different classes.

Therefore I have a project structure with a folder called train,test.
In the train folder I have 20 different folders ,each folder again has many files related to that particular class.ex:weather, atheism...etc

I have now created a train.arff file for the entire train folder.When the data is visualized through I can see only two attributes .
Have provided a link below:

[Screen in weka](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tgnhou1gba9yjn/doubt.jpg?dl=0)

My Doubt is how can i view the various files under these folders and remove the stopwords,punctuation,stemmin.How do I go about preprocessing.If some links to good resources are available please suggest and provide the necessary links

Comment: Can you send me these train texts in .arff format ? I need this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the videos below quite helpful when I first got my hands on text classification using Weka. You might want to take a look.

- [Weka Tutorial 31: Document Classification 1 (Application)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSZ9jQy1sfE)
- [Weka Tutorial 32: Document classification 2 (Application)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlVJ2_N_Olo)
- [WEKA Text Classification for First Time & Beginner Users](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY29uC4uem8)

You might want to use StringToWordVector filter to see the effect of each word as an attribute, which is indeed described in detail in the first and last video . Within the filter settings you can give a stopwords list and choose in each run to use it or not. Same with the stemming you can change it as well. This [documentation](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA) and videos will get you to understand it easily.